# GetOrgChart removing top bar, accesing click handlers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, getorgchart

I'm trying to implement GetOrgChart with asp.net mvc in a complex scheme but stuck with some issues...

- I need to remove top search bar. Tried to do this adding "display-none" to generated div's css class. But this resulted in main svg not filling screen, 'cause it's padding gets set to some value from inline styling.
- Is there any way to access add/edit/delete/view buttons' click handlers? I want to display a custom page for each operation. And can we disable individual buttons (i.e. add or edit) selectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the top bar you have to change the theme, lets assume that you are using "ula" theme, remove the top bar set getOrgChart.themes.ula.toolbarHeight = 0;

Regarding your second question use the following example as starting point:

http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Custom-Edit-Form

Comment: @kohlidi... did the first suggestion work for you? I was unable to remove the top bar using this method

Comment: @Dana we dumped this, but as far as i remember i used my own hack, and give up on this library altogether before my question got answered. hack was making toolbar invisible from css then adding container some minus top padding to compensate as far as i remember...

Comment: @kohlidi did you ditch the org chart visualization altogether, or did you replace it with something?

Comment: @Dana we ditched this, replaced it with existing svg with some added functionality... The company sent us specialized svg  they made then we processed it to be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the toolbar by overriding it's css

```
.get-org-chart .get-oc-tb {
    display: none;
}
```